# How to add a two different files under one ng-App

Tags: angularjs

I have the following files

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../public/javascripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/javascripts/spojsolver.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/javascripts/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="spojsolver">
<nav ng-controller ="NavCntrl" class="navbar navbar-default" >
<div >
    <a href="home.html" class="navbar-brand" >Home</a>
    <span ng-show = "!currentUser">
        <a href="login.html" class="navbar-brand" >Login</a> 
        <a href="register.html" class="navbar-brand">Register</a>  
    </span> 
    <span ng-show = "currentUser">
        <a href="logout.html" ng-click="logout()" class="navbar-brand">Logout</a> 
        <a href="profile.html" class="navbar-brand">Profile</a>
    </span>
</div> 
</nav>
<div class="container" ng-view=>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and then I have a file login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/stylesheets/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <h1 class="text-center login-title">Sign in to continue to SPOJ Solutions </h1>
            <div class="account-wall">
                <img class="profile-img" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/568733328090480640/B1rm7i-y_400x400.jpeg"
                    alt="">
                <form class="form-signin">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model = 'user.username' required autofocus>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model = 'user.password' required>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" ng-click = login(user) type="submit">
                    Sign in</button>
                <label class="checkbox pull-left">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
                    Remember me
                </label>
                <a href="#" class="pull-right need-help">Need help? </a><span class="clearfix"></span>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!--a href="#" class="text-center new-account">Create an account </a-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is I am using a function login(user) in login.html for which I have function defined in my login.js file in my index.html 
but I have no way of connecting my login.html to my index.html. How do I link two different files so that they are under same $rootScope so that I can validate across different pages.

Comment: If you're switching pages you lose your page's scope. First figure out if you want an actual SPA, otherwise you'll need to maintain data on the server side.

Comment: I am failing to get the exact meaning of SPA. Would you expand over it. It can't be having only single HTML file and accessing all other html from it using #file.html.

Comment: take a look at angular routing, either using [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute#!) or the excellent angular module [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). Both of these have the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: @SarasArya no, your understanding of a Single Page Application (SPA) is not correct.  In a SPA, you have a designated area of your page which is used to load templates, and you use a JavaScript function to dynamically load different templates in this area.  These templates *are not* full pages, they are snippets of HTML only.  your `<a>` links never refer to the file itself, they refer to functions which the framework uses to figure out which template to put in the `<ng-view>` (or `<ui-view>`, depending on your chosen framework).

Comment: @Claies how will ng-Route be useful in linking two different files? Well my Idea was to create an app for login.html and a controller for it and include it in the dependency of ng-app of index.html ... Would that work... Is that what you were hinting at?

Comment: yes, that's closer to how a SPA works; the index is the base of the app, all the pages are templates.

Comment: @Claies I don't want to sound rude but your explanation about SPA made little sense to me. If you could explain me by an example or probably point me towards a document from where you got your understanding clear about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did, I pointed you to the documentation for the two more popular modules people use to perform this task.

Comment: @Claies The explanation on one of the videos on youtube about SPA considered using hashes as the main criteria for creating SPA. Which looks correct but I can't believe that's about it ? Could you shed some light on it. And also if I include app that I created for login.html page and included it as a dependency, it will use the same $rootScope for the login app as well?

Comment: using hashes is the main criteria for a SPA? first, I can easily create a SPA without hashes, second, hashes have been around since HTML was created, and the first pages designed were certainly not Single Page Applications.  the characteristic of a SPA is one thing only - using JavaScript to manage the display of the page without making a full page reload.

Comment: Yeah I have cleared around a bit about my understanding of SPA. that in one page load, you load everything you need. So that when a user wants to go to a different page, instead of a full page reload. Only part of the page known as template is loaded. This is achieved by Asynchronous JavaScript n XML. which behind the scenes do all your job. without us knowing. Now one way to achieve this is using hashes. because what they really do is take you to a different part of page. But if you load in a new page. Wouldn't you be in a total different scope? How do you make a link. That's all I am asking?

Comment: yes, you are correct.  Loading a new page loads a new script with a new scope.  This is why a SPA *does not load new pages*. **period**.  It's a **Single Page Application**.  Angular Routing modules like ngRoute or ui-router allow you to make it seem as though you have loaded a new page, but they do not actually change pages.